# Use web service As Datasource in CRM reporting

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2012

I working with Reporting Service (SSRS) on CRM 2011 then

I want to use Web Service as DataSource. I make simple web service that query data from CRM Database (not Filtered)

then I call it's from report preview on VS2012 It's work fine but When I deploy my Report in CRM my report not working

when I use Filtered Entity in my web service with user `sa` when I test It's return 0 rows and also not working on CRM

Anyone can tell me Can I use Web service as  DataSource for run report on CRM ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use WebService as a datasource for CRM 2011. You have 2 ways - use SQL DataSource or FetchXml DataSource. You can read additional information here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx - same approaches would work for CRM 2011/2013/2015.